# How could I take screenshot & upload images with with js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I was wondering if anyone knows how could I make my own "Webpage screenshot taker"

Features would be

- select whole page
- select viewable area
- select area to take
- after selecting, upload it via my php script & save direct link to clipboard

Are there any tutorials/helful articles about doing this? How could I "post" image to my script? Via ajax? I think it's not possible

I would use any existing extension but problem is that they're all so complicated.

### UPDATE:

now it works, also sending ajax works but on my server I can't see binary data sent.

If I open chrome and look at form data sent, I see

```
boundary:Google_Chrome_Screen_Capture
dataList%5B0%5D%5BcontentType%5D:application/atom xml
dataList%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D:<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title>1312107206756.png</title><summary></summary><category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#photo"/></entry>
dataList%5B1%5D%5BcontentType%5D:image/png
dataList%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D:PNG


IHDR³¾~>-IDATx^íMnK¯P5²ôjPBÍ,
XO5 ±`èyÈYsDI63,FÈ]fFz[\Ý=j©:~22##* ý9÷0²ÉÌ8ç|qãfzíßÿýßBø8°FR¤ça&0f()03LBÉ&J
Yûç¿þÃïÌäÂµù¡"Ô;@Õ#caÆÉR½Â¬3Nêfõà@q²T¯0«GÇÂ¥z%Y=8f,Õ !ÌêÀ10ãd©^ aV'KõJ³zp Ì8YªWBÕ#caÆÉR½Â¬3Nêfõà@q²T¯0«GÇÂ¥z%Y=8f,Õ !ÌêÀ10ãd©^  aV'KõJ³zp Ì8YªWBÕ#caÆÉR½Â¬3Nêfõà@q²T¯0«GÇÂ¥z%Y=8f,Õ !ÌêÀ10ãd©^  aV'KõJ³zp Ì8YªWBÕ#caÆÉR½Â¬3Nêfõà@q²T¯0«GÇÂ¥z%Y=8f,Õ !ÌêÀ10ãd©^  aV'KõJ³zp Ì8YªWBÕ#caÆÉR½Â¬3Nêfõà@q²T¯0«GÇÂ¥z%Y=8f,Õ !ÌêÀ10ãd©^  aV'KõJ³zp Ì8YªWBÕ#caÆÉR½Â¬3Nêfõà@q²T¯0«GÇÂ¥z%Y=8f,Õ !ÌêÀ10ãd©^  aV'KõJ³zp Ì8YªWBÕ#caÆÉR½Â¬3Nêfõà@q²T¯0«GÇÂ¥z%Y=8èyz ¯ßýÏåÑú5ys]³ßaøKÂ|.ööE®Fg®ÎÊéÁk_Êã«³m¼ækÖ72Û¶ëøµ~\·cu0_µíý6a¾êìxÌ¾:Èß²éª¹rþI|Ñ}$ëî¸üÍÿ@½üS|a«h";òÂ>c31#újØòLåàõ;ñ3eóÄëHç¦9ìñXw|[áîÉv¾þlqÙ÷7'2ÉdëÍ¼¨Õbf±Þ¬õë×lÕA§ÓÏ­çÎû$9òð©È~ü|e¼ëÀá÷ÓÃÙÉþùcynIðûyfÊ8àüÓ¼mËKO|Þf¬½ÃþYÒ¡l¾´DÓ3|»7ÌÆË4ner¸×å¨upÛådc¥ì²gÏµû¹Í¦lÕâ×üîG¼3ø*ÚLqð¦Á^Â¼t§9- ûòÔ»w.M³=9l{áÌÒEEûäº9íaC4=ß*«ßãiXßºÙwÅÏå¢çïúÿ­à×¶ùïqeNµUÛ{*<$ÌKáMoX-f¢ò*±-³}µ{á/µÙí/¸ÖâäþlHq6«Z¡;   mCÓ3¢vÄ¶®åIª´ º5sTZ¨hj3éõZìüaÓû9ja®ÙÅ&hð0¯óÑ?'Yoì¸Ý£Ù¦üØÈÚtÈüø· ÀÅÕ3ô«¦¹.úï¶gv¦ÜªdÏlßb­¾­£k.µQ[z¾e^÷UÜ ³ý"Tò0¯ó«W¯wB¯WásâeÛJðFý§«ÚéË\ö.}ÑrÁ1qmz]ÏìO×«Oþ|­µaÇsD=s¸÷Å®Z[çÉNyæß!â{{ôÌÖcoÊí×¿½|¯5ük½úkëäZCdýyøbÑpç÷Fß£72øÜmoï¡  U±ækF©zF,¼:;ð£/#¾f´´a#ÕÍSþµ`µmùÚc?ïtô#öðÎiå&3ÿ"ÎÁÚYýÎl:ZçWõWøz@·ÅÌ¾ÉÍü©÷¶8ÀuÀ8pÉ¿Âø@!f)Á;@I&J
!ÌdÆÂ%f2ãaB3q0ÃDI!À8@a¢¤ÂL` Ì0QRa&0f()03LBÉ&J
!ÌdÆÂ%f2ãaBÖ¾|ù² 
tÁµ?f$©A3!q0ÃDI!À8@a¢¤ÂL` Ì0QRa&0f()03LBÉ&J
!ÌdÆÂ%f2ãaB3q0ÃDI!À8@a¢¤ÂL` Ì0QRa&0f()03LÒóüL>^È½Ý-ùcú>·Êé½}çìûÜeÖzÏÆú~¾Éõ´åvY\=Ì¿Â¾Fô}îWh¼ì`þðöÃb8ËtzaìÊøÉÜ|ã÷åÌ8OrWéÔã»Ï.{í}ÇfÁT¦~0=Ü­¼ÔGóGf¦¹·ìü!¹¹||{Ù3nÞ3¹5{¾ËûÓ¡<Ù96ëÌÍcõÓ¦s¢»öT²÷IÕ³lÍnÌ©X7WÓÛeî~¾ÜÛÉYMÍ~E;§IÏÒl;¸j*,Kç)|[ûðöíâl8';we`áø,>ì¶\¹6A´æÙ!²céðÙ¹ïåt]û<Ï6SaÄüÛDeË=oþh6]Øùµ?¾;:Ïc7]Cb`¼7×Å=Ù-v^¶¨Ì¼:ÏÄ^;aØl-ã;/"½ÝæîãKÖ*®K1Kò&Ï»Q³¾øZ2OìÙÐUK[    M)µÕQ¢9Ý5 õÝ¥q|åÕ/;¯ÌFU¶3·|óãÌ`wkP¿VkDë<Q@±ÆD÷{¼¾à°¹Ö³xÝîöx6½   4s'ÕÎEÕÑ®Å U~4´1Ñg¶ÊÜÔ$y%ÉªåÙÈÀ=¸f#H=
0çÁÚ£Ò¶¡åÉ~OOæI
ÖÍZ«Fh»âtRðü    ã<ËÚ'ûûç¬ÝqmZXc_Uo×¹ÓuØÍÖÑKÀÜ¨§²*ÍKÇè
sYó-¬Ìac}~1PG¡BZ«DZÛ*s]%NIa7aRµ;DM§@kó¨«/½`nÑÓ¹2w£7ÌEf¾g=ô½aÜÓV(zAß»ª½õ²ª¸BYÑõö¥Ë÷×iïÜsMoÞ¡gNûûrhªÁRÏB»S¼°¶½#T®5¶ñ¼/}`®6ÓSjÑÒÖ.i*¼f^0³uÙæ @ü5#û]jÉAöòe¯ÇcØ±UøÊ£ãu4ñÜÍ¥¯)î¹ä FxQM7PÝï¥¢ë×º#ôÁ§¶{¨ñÌþ%Õýs_h¦ð5&^GEoÜjDs7ëìêÿ2äòlû:lF=qZëy1P§1zÂìßK|«QéÛ¶k¼ÚÚ5N»úÐÕyõ1Z*YÍ`ßm³½â¯z-ê÷~èÂ*E0°©Þ6ûÂÜW¯yîÛ\îÞ]éï°·Í´YÏÿÈ>ãÝbIEND®B`
```

however when I try

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

on target machine, it outputs everything except data

```
 Array
                (
                    [boundary] => Google_Chrome_Screen_Capture
                    [dataList] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [contentType] => application/atom+xml
                                    [data] => <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title>1312107206756.png</title><summary></summary><category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#photo"/></entry>
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [contentType] => image/png
                                )

                        )

                )
```

is it configuration of server or extension fault?

### UPDATE2:

as [serg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886527/how-could-i-take-screenshot-upload-images-with-with-js/6887875#6887875) suggested, I have sent my image in base64 code encoding. It worked and I saved image on my server, however it does send only blank image

base64 data looks like:

```
dataList%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D: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 wplGMsKZVAPDosOiw4XCi8OcwpXDssOycsKwHh8bG0MuwpfCk37DjEIjwp1OY8OHwo7DlwnCgHFSOD4hVsKUwpTClMKiwqTCpMKEw6tgMsK8wp51wofCgl3CrMKDRkfDh0jCpsKGwq7CrsKvw5DDnMOcwqwkQGNAwpggw6zDnMK5EwcOHAAlUF8gwrZvw5/DgQFjTsKwO8OoVVFRwoEXNybCsHTDqVLCvMO/w4HCh8Kuw6dEIsKBwrdaw5/DhsOtw5vCt8KDworDpkwdIwBLCcKIw4PChw/CqwPDgcOWIxgTGhoaw5DDksOSwoLCtsK2NgUgwrYjR8Kowo8bYATCtXbDhsKMGXjCu8O1LcKsWcKzBsKbwpPDjcKuw6dNwps2w6HDmcOnw5bDo8OWwq1bQUVjwpxCwoN1UnlZaTAgwobCh8KHw7PDi8KWLcOjwr3Cs2XDixZ 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 Sj16P8KyWcK9eg1ywrHDkGDDocOKw4A ecKyNxgQQcOrwojCl17DnsKEw4F/LlPCnsK4w4nDq8KJwqAXwqPDrcOMwpkzw7lnLMOXeD3Cj8KMwowEFcKtD8KfNGrDjMKtwq3DgcKpH04GB0JFwqNZUD3Dv3wCw6fDj8O/w40rODZcw50zF8KZw4IqS3bDj8KfX8KLH388wqUOw4TDoMOgYMKgEsK7wqfCpwcLFz7CgsKKwopKwo7DvEQYcTfCgGPCicO8w4zCmcOfw4FqEsKVK8OQChUrwoUzwpkMwr/Ch8KGwoZUw6RPWRtWwr3DjsKbNw8rKcOxwqpcw5rCpUvCl8OuIW7Cq8KYHMK8wo3DiixZwqNGw797IFTCoMKLwoAwUMKKwoDCiMKAEAMmYkTDhMKIwogRw5JBJArCjSg0wqLDkMKIQsODwq/DgsKMcsKEwoHDjn8vwp3CncOReT3CmRgAAAAASUVORMKuQmDCgg==
```

and my image (saved) is [here](http://phpcode.eu/images/1312129942.png)

What can I do now?

Comment: You can't (without writing a BHO for IE using JScript or something). You can use Java.

Comment: Okay. for google chrome? I mean.. as extension. Added to tags

Comment: Are you trying to automate something? I suppose you could using plugins/addons for a particular browser, but I unfortunately would not know how to do that. :( At least not any more than you would at this point. :)

Comment: You might look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504034/take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-page-in-java

Comment: You might also check the Chrome Web Store for apps that may have code you can check for how they capture screenshots. For instance, this extension seems to do what you're asking: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9935/take-screenshots-of-any-webpage-in-google-chrome/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: it looks fine (that linked extension), however, I did not find code?. 1. I'm looking for google-chrome solution, does java work in Gchrome?

Comment: That might have been a bad example seeing your other comments after I posted it. Here is the source code for Google's Screen Capture extension: http://code.google.com/p/chrome-screen-capture/source/checkout

Comment: I don't think your data preamble is right. What kind of file is it (png, jpg, gif, etc...)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2002/discussion-between-genesis-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript cannot take screenshots unless it is within an extension ([drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow%28%29)). However, if you are looking to do something similar to the [Google Feedback](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/index.html) tool, which does not take a screenshot, but builds an image mimicking the page based on the DOM, then [this experimental project](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) may be of interest to you. Some examples of the script in use [here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Another option is to use a server to take the screenshot for you, but then it isn't what the user sees, but what the server sees, and that may or may not be what you are after (with PHP, see [imagegrabscreen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php) and [imagegrabwindow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php)).

For Chrome extensions, Google has an [open source extension](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-screen-capture/) which allows you to select a region or the whole page for screen capture. With a little modification, you could make it upload the screenshot to your server with AJAX.

Comment: No. I'm looking for js google-chrome extension to create screenshot of specified area. Like this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdddabjhelpilpnpgondfmehhcplpiin) but to upload it to my own hosting

Comment: You can look at the source code for most of the extensions. For instance, this one (by Google) allows you to select a portion of a page: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg Posting it to your website should be fairly simply after that.

Comment: Check out this open source extension http://code.google.com/p/chrome-screen-capture/ by Google.

Comment: @Niklas: thanks. But, how could I upload it with ajax? I though ajax does not support POST

Comment: @genesis That isn't an issue with extensions with correct permissions.

Comment: If you're doing an extension, you have a lot more latitude to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Niklas could you review my uploade please?

Comment: @genesis Check what's present in `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_data"]`

Comment: @Niklas: print_R($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);die();
 -> nothing

Comment: @Niklas: Please take a look at my **UPDATE2**

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Please take a look at my **UPDATE2**

Comment: how do you explain google ability to take screenshots for bug reports in google websites?? go to google maps (for example) and select FEEDBACK at the bottom of the page. It takes a screenshot and sends it to google. And that's no extension.

Comment: @Zibri Similarly to https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas, for more information see http://www.elliottsprehn.com/preso/fluentconf

Answer (score 2):

Chrome extension API allows [taking screenshot](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) only of a visible area of a current tab, that's it. If you need more (whole page or inactive tab) you would need to create a NPAPI plugin (C++ dll).

Once you got the screenshot (in is encoded in [DataURI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (base64) format) you can write it into `<canvas>` element for editing. You can resize it, crop, and anything you like (you have full control over each pixel).

After editing you can again import the screenshot from `<canvas>` to DataURI and send it via ajax (POST or GET) to your php script. Extensions are allowed to make [cross domain ajax requests](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/xhr.html).

Comment: thanks. Everything works except that last step (sending it to the server). Please review my **UPDATE** in question

Comment: @genesis Don't send screenshot as a binary data. Send it in DataURI format and then decode it on php side.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, it worked. however, it is showing only blank image (result). Could you look at it in my **UPDATE2** please?

Comment: @genesis To test it assign that string to some `<img>` on the page before sending and see what's inside.

Comment: please come to our [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2002/discussion-between-genesis-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite screenshot taking and manipulation extension for Chrome [**Awesome Screenshot**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce).

Comment: I know this is awesome plugin, hwoever I'm looking to code which would help me to create new one

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely true: how do you explain google ability to take screenshots for bug reports in google websites? go to google maps (for example) and select FEEDBACK at the bottom of the page. It takes a screenshot and sends it to google. And that's no extension.

Comment: The feedback tool doesn't take a screenshot. It just clones the HTML, and sends that information to Google. The screenshot is probably reconstructed at the server's side using the given information. An easy way to demonstrate this is by launching a local file server, and use the webkit inspector to add an extra style, e.g. `background-image:url("http://localhost:8080/whatever.png")`. You'll see that the image won't show up at the feedback tool.