# How to take a webpage screenshot?

Tags: screenshot, java

I am using this code below but the image generated is broken. I think probably it is because of the renderization options. Does anybody know what is happening?

```
package webpageprinter;

import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WebPagePrinter {
private BufferedImage image = null;

public BufferedImage Download(String webpageurl) {
try
{
    URL url = new URL(webpageurl);
    final JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
    jep.setContentType("text/html");
    ((HTMLDocument)jep.getDocument()).setBase(url);
    jep.setEditable(false);
    jep.setBounds(0,0,1024,768);
    jep.addPropertyChangeListener("page",new
    PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    try
    {
        image = new
        BufferedImage(1024,768,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        jep.paint(graphics);
        ImageIO.write(image,"png",new File("C:/webpage.png"));
    }
    catch (Exception re)
    {
        re.printStackTrace();
    }
    }});
    jep.setPage(url);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
return image;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new WebPagePrinter().Download("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: *"the image generated is somehow broken"*  A picture paints a thousand words.  Rather than say those thousand words, why not upload an picture for us to look at?  And if you can get it to break @ 400x300px (as opposed to 1024x768px), all the better.

Comment: [See my answer using Selenium with a real browser][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504034/take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-page-in-java/7583391#7583391

Answer (score 4):

I think there are 3 problems and one fragility in that code:

#### Problems

1. `JEditorPane` was never intended to be a browser.
2. `setPage(URL)` loads asynchronously.  It is necessary to add a listener to determine when the page has loaded.
3. You might find some sites automatically refuse connections to Java clients.

#### Fragility

The fragile nature is included with the call to `setBounds()`.  Use layouts.

#### Image at 400x600

[image: Google screen shot]

But looking at this image, it seems 3 does not apply here, 2 is not the problem.  It comes down to point 1.  `JEditorPane` was never intended as a browsing component.  Those random characters at the bottom are JavaScript that the JEP is not only not scripting, but then improperly displaying in the page.

Comment: Thanks for uploading the image.

Comment: My intention with this code is to shot a webpage without been on it from time to time. I want to display the image in a large screen here at my office and for that I already have a HTML code that does that. I still have to implement the timer in the Java code, but do you have some suggestions about what should I use instead of JEditorPane?

Comment: Sorry, it is not something I've looked much into.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an entire screen capture using Java Robot [(API Here)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class RobotExp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            // Capture the screen shot of the area of the screen defined by the rectangle
            BufferedImage bi=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C:/imageTest.jpg"));

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This example was found [here.](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/how-to-capture-screenshot.html) With some modifications by me.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried this, but my focus is to shot a webpage without been on it. I want to improve the code later to take screenshots from time to time automatically. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using Java's `JEditorPane` to render the webpage, which has a very limited HTML rendering engine. It is simply not able to display more complex webpages as well as a modern Browser.

If you need to produce screenshots of correctly rendered complex webpages using Java, the best way is probably to [use Selenium to control a real browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver) like Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc states](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)

> HTML text. The kit used in this case is the class
>   javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit which provides HTML 3.2 support.

Probably that explains why the page looks a bit broken, as nowadays pages are mostly using HTML4, 5 or XHTML.....

There's an article here on SO regarding Java browser components: [Best Java/Swing browser component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [flying-saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/). Great for generating images and pdf's from HTML pages.

Comment: Their page specifies XHTML, did you try it with HTML4 or 5?

Comment: I use it in combination with JSoup (http://jsoup.org/) when the HTML is not valid XHTML - Jsoup.parse(loadedHTML)

Comment: Warning: It doesn't include JS support at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had best results with Selenium WebDriver using a VirtualFramebuffer and Firefox Binary. 
This is tested under ubuntu. You need to have xvfb and Firefox installed. Advantage: You are running a real browser, so the screenshot looks like a real screenshot in a real browser.

First install Firefox and virtual framebuffer:

> aptitude install xvfb firefox

Compile and run this class, open /tmp/screenshot.png afterwards

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CaptureScreenshotTest
{
    private static int DISPLAY_NUMBER=99;
    private static String XVFB="/usr/bin/Xvfb";
    private static String XVFB_COMMAND= XVFB + " :" + DISPLAY_NUMBER;
    private static String URL="http://www.google.com/";
    private static String RESULT_FILENAME="/tmp/screenshot.png";

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(XVFB_COMMAND);
        FirefoxBinary firefox = new FirefoxBinary();
        firefox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":" + DISPLAY_NUMBER);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox, null);
        driver.get(URL);
        File scrFile = ( (TakesScreenshot) driver ).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(RESULT_FILENAME));
        driver.close();
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```