# Is there any way we can also take the screenshot of entire page including the page which is there in down (scrollbar) using wedriver

Tags: java

I need to capture the full page of IE browser. I am using web driver. Pls help me.

below code is used to capture the present window only.

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504034/take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-page-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can change the browser to full screen before taking the screenshot. This is the code:

```
private void changeToFullScreen() {
    try {
        Robot r;
        r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F11);
        r.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F11);
        driver.sleep(2);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        log.error("It was not possible to maximize", e)
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change the screen size, you can obtain the browser height and take screenShots while you scroll down until the bottom (can be done with Robot):

```
int numberOfScrolls = pageHeight / browserHeight;
for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfScrolls ; i++){
   takeScreenshot();
   scrollDown(browserHeight);
}
concatenateScreenshots();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;

public class TakeScreenshotWithScroll {
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        String key = "webdriver.gecko.driver";
        String value = "driver/geckodriver.exe";
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty(key, value);
        driver.get("ENTER THE URL HERE");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Screenshot fpScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
        ImageIO.write(fpScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("D:///FullPageScreenshot.png"));
    }
}
```

Here is the download link of [aShot](http://central.maven.org/maven2/ru/yandex/qatools/ashot/ashot/1.5.3/ashot-1.5.3.jar) Jar file