# Batik - Convert HTML, CSS & SVG into an image

Tags: java, html, image, batik, image-conversion

We can successfully convert an SVG into an image with Batik, however, I need to convert a whole HTML Div, with SVG implemented within, along with its CSS presentation code, into an image.

Are there any modules / support within Batik for achieving this? Here is a screenshot of 
HTML, CSS & SVG which needs to be end output.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Do you really need Batik for rendering the SVG? [Taking a screenshot of a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504034/take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-page-in-java) could also work for you since most (headless) browsers support SVG.

Comment: @ComFreek we did consider Phantom.js but we actually output the above data within our app so we only want a small subset of the rendered page.

Comment: I am not sure if such headless browsers support restricting the screenshot to a single div. Nevertheless, I think you would have better chances for an answer over at http://softwarerecs.stackexhange.com. (Be sure to list all your requirements including your app's environment [Android, iOS?].)