# Take the screenshot of the webpage using java

Tags: java, api

I'am trying to take the screenshot of the webpage using java code. I am using google api to get the screenshot.But it has only limited offer and not free.Can anyone help me to get the code

Comment: you can use phantomjs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7583391/1475228

Answer (score 0):

In a webpage you can use a `html2canvas` in HTML 5.

For more you can read [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/08/take-webpage-screenshot-html5-jquery-javascript.html).

Something like this:

> To run html2canvas on an element with some options simply call:
>
> ```
> html2canvas(element, options);
> ```
>
> The rendered canvas is provided in the callback event onrendered, as
>   such:
>
> ```
> html2canvas(element, {
>     onrendered: function(canvas) {
>         // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
>     }
> });
> ```

For more read here: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html.

To do it Java read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7583391/1475228).